# encryption decryption of streaming delta table in azure databricks

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

My goal:
my goal is to encrypt and decrypt streaming delta table in azure databricks in python.

I am trying to get the solution for encryption and decryption of streaming delta table in python so far I am able to achieve column level encryption however can I encrypt the entire table at once instead of encrypting column one by one
please provide me with the relevant solution for the encryption and decryption of entire table

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, lit, md5
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
# Register UDF's
encrypt = udf(encrypt_val, StringType())
decrypt = udf(decrypt_val, StringType())
# Fetch key from secrets
# encryptionKey = dbutils.preview.secret.get(scope = "encrypt", key = "fernetkey")
encryptionKey = key
encryptionKey2 = key2

# Encrypt the data 
df = spark.table("EncryptTest")
encrypted = df.withColumn("ssn", encrypt("ssn",lit(encryptionKey)))\
              .withColumn("Address", encrypt("Address",lit(encryptionKey2)))
display(encrypted)
#Save encrypted data 
encrypted.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").option("overwriteSchema", "true").saveAsTable("Encryption_Test_Table")

decrypted = encrypted.withColumn("ssn", decrypt("ssn",lit(encryptionKey)))\
              .withColumn("Address", decrypt("Address",lit(encryptionKey2)))
display(decrypted)
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Creating a table

[image]

Step 2: Inserting a record

[image]

Step 3: Installation and create a fernet key

[image]

Step 4: Example for fernet

[image]

Step 5: Create UDFs in encrypting a value and decrypting a value

[image]

Step 6: Using AzureKey valut and store it in secrets

encryptionKey = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "test", key = "fernet")
Refer below link

https://hevodata.com/learn/databricks-secret/#65

[image]

Step 7: Use the UDF in a dataframe to encrypt a column

[image]

Step 8: Use the UDF in a data frame to decrypted a column

[image]